# How to find the intersection between two columns from two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to compare two different columns from two different DataFrames.

```
test_website1 
          Domain
0      www.google.com
1    www.facebook.com
2       www.yahoo.com

test_website2 
          Domain
0      www.bing.com
1    www.instagram.com
2       www.google.com
```

---

```
testlist = []

def match_domain(col1, col2):
    for a in col1:
        v1 = a
        for b in col2:
            v2 = b
            if v2 == v1:
                testlist.append(v1)
```

---

```
test_website1 = df_website_test1['Domain']
test_website2 = df_website_test2['Domain']
```

When I call:

```
match_domain(test_website1, test_website2)
```

The output should be just "www.google.com"

but instead this is the output I get.

```
['www.google.com', 'www.facebook.com', 'www.yahoo.com']
```

Completely Stuck! Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do this in pandas is an inner [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) (default is `how='inner'`):

```
pd.merge(df1['Domain'], df2['Domain'])

#            Domain
# 0  www.google.com
```

If you really want a list, chain [`tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
pd.merge(df1['Domain'], df2['Domain'])['Domain'].tolist()

# ['www.google.com']
```